# Loopback "loaded" operation hook not being called

Tags: loopbackjs

Loopback "loaded" operation hook not being called.

```
  Post.observe('loaded', function logQuery(ctx, next) {
    console.log('In loaded');
    console.log('CTX %s', JSON.stringify(ctx));
    next();
  });
```

for "access" it is working fine,

```
  Post.observe('access', function logQuery(ctx, next) {
    console.log('Accessing %s matching %s', ctx.Model.modelName, ctx.query.where);
    console.log('Accessing  matching %s', JSON.stringify(ctx));
    next();
  });
```

Let me know if I missed something in "loaded" hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're using the model. The doc's note that `loaded` only works for the following built-in methods:

- find()
- findOne()
- findById()
- exists()
- count()
- create()
- upsert()
  (same as updateOrCreate())
- findOrCreate()*
- prototype.save()
- prototype.updateAttributes()

source: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-loaded

I'm not one to overly rely on the loopback docs, due to the fact they reguarly have key bits of info left out... but this may offer a reason.

Here's what it says about the `access` hook:

> The access hook is triggered whenever a database is queried for models, that is when any create, retrieve, update, and delete method of PersistedModel is called.

So I think you need to check on the methods you're using to test your code on these models.